# Save every fourth item in a list to a key in dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics, biopython

I need to save every fourth item of a list as a key in python, then starting at 5 every fourth item as a value, and starting at 6 every fourth item as a value (the value will be a list)

I have a text file that looks like this:
GeneID  NumC    NumL    NumP
ENSEMBL001  15  5   30
ENSEMBL002  60  0   10
ENSEMBL003  25  5   41
ENSEMBL004  20  7   0
ENSEMBL005  40  22  67
ENSEMBL006  81  77  9
ENSEMBL007  2   88  2
ENSEMBL008  8   62  90

and I want to make a dictionary where the "ENSEMBL" value is the key and the first two numbers are the value associated with that key

I have the code written for the first value of the dictionary:

```
    dict_lung = {
        file_name[4] : (file_name[5], file_name[6])
    }
```

When printed, this will be a dictionary with key ENSEMBL001 and value (15,5)

What I want to do is have the dictionary go through the entire text file and save these values. for example, the next key and value saved in the dictionary will be

```
file_name[8] : (file_name[9], file_name[10])
```

I have tried to make a for loop but keep getting errors, any help would be appreciated

Comment: So write a loop that does it. Are you familiar with loops?

Comment: Yes I wrote a loop and I got a ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: I am having trouble writing the loop

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: i=4
   j=5
   k=6
    for i,j,k in list:
        dict_lung = {
                file_name[i] : (file_name[j], file_name[k])
         }
        i+4
        j+4
        k+4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically this is a hard-coded problem. It based in the logic you used:

but you can use the following loop, where MAX will be the maximum number of allowed indices (**Don't forget that you need to careful with exceeding the list**):

```
for i in range(4, MAX, 4):
    dict_lung = { file_name[i] : (file_name[i+1], file_name[i+2]) }
```

From the commented loop:

```
i=4 j=5 k=6 
for i,j,k in list: 
    dict_lung = { file_name[i] : (file_name[j], file_name[k]) } 
    i+4 j+4 k+4
```

I'm not sure what `list` is but it's not a list that contain tuples of 3. please read about unpacking in python https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/